# Generalized operator norm triangle inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Let $O_1, \cdots, O_n$ be Hermitian operators and $c_1, \cdots, c_n$ be complex numbers. If $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the operator norm, does the following inequality hold?

$$\| \sum_{i=1}^N c_i O_i \| \le \max_{\{f_i\} = \pm 1} \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^N c_i f_i \| O_i \| \bigg|$$

In other words, we take the maximum over all sign combinations of the individual operator norms, but we do not take the absolute value of the complex numbers $c_i$.

Comment: False. Try two-by-two matrices, e.g., {{0,1},{0,0}}.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA your example is not Hermitian. Do you have a Hermitian counterexample?

Comment: I believe that what @NarutakaOZAWA had in mind is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2\\0&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\1&0\end{pmatrix} -i \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle what if, instead of operator norm, I consider the numerical radius? That is, $r(A) = \sup_{\| u\|_2 = 1} |\langle u | A | u \rangle|$.

Comment: In that case, the inequality holds, because $\langle u | O_i |u\rangle \in [ -\|O_i\|,\|O_i\|]$, so $\langle u | \sum_i c_i O_i |u\rangle$ can be written as convex combination of $\sum \pm c_i \|O_i\|$.

Comment: Thank you so much! And one last thing @MikaeldelaSalle: if we continue to use numerical radius, but extend to the case that $O_i$ are products of Hermitian operators, does the result still hold?